# Rising and Falling in Tradingview PineScript does not produce correct results

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to find if an instrument closing price is rising or falling by looking back last 2 bars.

Below is the pinescript in tradingview.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
plot(close)

a=1
a:=ta.rising(close,2) ? 1 : ta.falling(close,2) ? -1 : nz(a[1],0)
plotshape(a,"a")
```

However in the below chart, the current closing price is **0.1801** which is lower than the previous 2 bars close and wondering why it still populates 1 as result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You should be getting a warning like below which you shouldn't ignore:

> The function 'ta.falling' should be called on each calculation for
> consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary
> operator or from the scope.

2. With this `nz(a[1],0)` statement, you are assigning the previous value of `a` to `a` if both your checks fail. This is why you are getting 1 there. Because the previous value of `a` is 1. Both `ta.rising` and `ta.falling` will return `false` at the bar you marked.

Change it to below code and it should be more clear.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
plot(close)

_n = input.int(2)

_r = ta.rising(close, _n)
_f = ta.falling(close, _n)
a = ta.rising(close, _n) ? 1 : ta.falling(close, _n) ? -1 : 0
b = _r ? 1 : _f ? -1 : 0

plotshape(a,"a", color=color.green)
plotshape(b,"b", color=color.red)
```

Comment: I understand that its assigning previous value of a to a only if the other two conditions returns false. If i may ask, why does it the particular closing price is not falling under the ta.falling logic even though its closing price is lower than the closing price of previous two bars?

Comment: It needs to be consecutively. The red bar's close is lower than the previous one. However, that is not true for the previous bar..

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I wasn't thinking of consecutive success / failure bars.